# Filter and search is not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, filters, search

This is my first post .. Please Help me. Problem is i can update my selected data .. but search and filter fields are not working .. Please guide me how can i bind my wrap class with page reference search and filter..

[image: vf page]

### Apex Controller

```
public class SController
{
    public List wrapList {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    public list Accounts;
    public string finalSearchValue{get;set;}
    public string fullname{get;set;}
    public List Add{get;set;}
    public list search{get;set;}
    public list Remove{get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
    public string Option{get;set;}

    public SController()
    {
        Accounts = [select Id, Name, Active__c, Phone from Account];
        if(wrapList == null)
        {
            wrapList = new List();
            for(Account a: Accounts)
            {
                wrapList.add(new wrapData(a));
            }
        }        
    }

    public pagereference AddStatus()
    {
        Add = new List();

        for(wrapData ch : wrapList)
        {
            if(ch.selected == true && ch.ac.Active__c=='No')
            {
                ch.ac.Active__c='Yes';
                Add.add(ch.ac);
            }
        }
        update Add;
        return null;
    }

    public pagereference RemoveStatus()
    {
        Remove = new List();

        for(wrapData ch : wrapList)
        {
            if(ch.selected == true && ch.ac.Active__c=='Yes')
            {
                ch.ac.Active__c='No';
                Remove.add(ch.ac);
            }
        }
        update Remove;
        return null;
    }

    public pagereference Search()
    {
        String finalSearchValue = '%' + fullname + '%';
        Accounts = [Select Id, Name, Active__c
        FROM Account
        where Name like :finalSearchValue];
        return null;
    }

    public List getOptions()
    {
        List Option = new List();
        Option.add(new selectOption('none','None'));
        Option.add(new selectOption('y','Active Accounts'));
        Option.add(new selectOption('n','Inactive Accounts'));
        Option.add(new selectOption('c','All Accounts'));             
        return Option;
    } 

    public void FetchData(string opt)    
    {
        Option = opt;
        if(opt=='y')
        {
            Accounts = [Select Id, Name, Active__c FROM Account where Active__c = 'Yes' ];
        }
        else if(opt=='n')
        {
            Accounts = [Select Id, Name, Active__c FROM Account where Active__c = 'No'];
        }
        else if(opt == 'c' || opt =='none')
        {
            Accounts = [Select Id, Name, Active__c FROM Account];
        } 
    }

    public pagereference Filter()
    {   
        List Option = new List();
        FetchData(value);
        return null;
    }

    public class wrapData
    {
        public Account us {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;} 
        public wrapData(Account a)
        {
            ac = a;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```
 <apex:page controller="SController">
  <script type="text/javascript">  
    function selectAllCheckboxes(ch,receivedInputID)
    {
        var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++)
        {
            if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1)
            {
                inputCheckBox[i].checked = ch.checked;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Inactive Account" action="{!RemoveStatus}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Active Account" action="{!AddStatus}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>             
        <table> <tr> <td> <apex:selectList value="{!Value}" size="1"> 
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"/> 
        </apex:selectList></td>
        <td><apex:commandButton value="filter" action="{!filter}"/></td>
        <td><apex:inputText value="{!fullname}" html-placeholder="Search" /></td>
        <td><apex:commandButton value="search" action="{!Search}" /></td></tr></table>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapList}" var="Wrap">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Wrap.selected}" id="inputId"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Full Name" value="{!Wrap.ac.Name}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!Wrap.ac.Phone}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!Wrap.ac.Active__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock> 
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that the code where you find actual accounts is not returned in wrapper format

```
    public pagereference Search()
    {
        String finalSearchValue = '%' + fullname + '%';
        Accounts = [Select Id, Name, Active__c FROM Account
                    where Name like :finalSearchValue];
        wraplist = new list<wrapData>();  
        for(Account a: Accounts)
        {
            wrapList.add(new wrapData(a));
        }
       return null;
   }
```

Same way apply for filter method as well.